# Remote MySQL Connection returns System Error: 111 or PDO error [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, pdo

Recently I moved my database to another host, and after setting it up, I can't connect to it from my application server using PHP or from anywhere from that matter except from the server itself.

PHP will return the following:
**Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**

I also tested on this website: http://www.rainbowspuppiessunshine.com/tools/dbtest/index.php
And the error returned was:
**Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111**

What I have already tried or checked:

- The my.cnf file has no bind-address, nor skip-networking
- It won't work even with bind-address set to the server's IP address
- The user on MySQL has all the permissions, including accepting from Any host
- MySQL server is listening on port 3306
- There are no firewalls set up that could be blocking port 3306
- Socket file is there

So basically every advice ever given on the internet for these errors did not fix the problem.

Here is the my.cnf file:

```
[mysql]


port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]


user                           = mysql
default_storage_engine         = MyISAM
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid_file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

key_buffer_size                = 2G
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP


max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000


datadir = /database/database/mysql


log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

tmpdir = /database/database/mysqltmp

tmp_table_size                 = 2G

max_heap_table_size            = 2G

query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size = 64M
max_connections = 1500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 1024
table_open_cache               = 5000


max_length_for_sort_data       = 4096

innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 8M


log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just tested if I could connect to the server via telnet on the MySQL port. The connection was successfull

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is misconfigured, and is looking for the mysql socket file in the wrong place. See [mysql.default_socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php) in your php.ini and make SURE it EXACTLY matches the path specified in your my.cnf file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Marc. In which server should I check that? The database server or the application server? Thank you again

Comment: two physically separate boxes? In that case, your client box (php system) should be using TCP to connect to mysql. Using the socket file is a unix-domain socket, which is purely local - you'd only be able to connect via that on the mysql box.